# how to use am/is/are + passive infinitive?

Tags: infinitives, passive-voice

I have problem with the meaning of following sentence and its grammatical structure.

> If they are to be believed

How is this different from

> If they are believed

When do we use *am/is/are + passive infinitive*?

Comment: Welcome. I think it would be better to submit three separate questions (or perhaps two because the second is simply an error). Note that, "*He'd (he had) took a sick day*" is grammatically incorrect -- the past participle of 'to take' is 'taken'. You can say, "*He'd taken a sick day*" or "*He took a sick day.*"

Comment: *to be believed* is a [passive infinitive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/infinitive-active-or-passive), thus my edit to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb "be" is among **modal** verbs (like "must", "should", "ought", etc.) and used to express a pre-existing agreement or common sense perception of behavior.

> We ***are*** to arrive to New York terminal at 6:15pm.

meaning: if all goes well, the train/bus will be there at that time, according to the schedule or timetable.

> John ***was*** to give a lecture on the 16th.

meaning: John was put in charge of giving the lecture (and agreed to do it).

The phrase

> If they ***are*** to be believed...

means that "If *common sense suggests* that we/you should believe them..." or that "if, *according to some predefined plan or agreement*, we/you accept what they are saying as truth..."

In comparison,

> If they *are believed*...

is a supposition of acceptance of "their" statements as true, simple passive voice.

Comment: *Be* is a **non-modal** auxiliary.

Answer (score 0):

It's a subtle difference, but "If they are to be believed" questions whether someone *should* believe them, as opposed to whether someone *does* believe them.

<sub>(Admittedly, even that doesn't seem to fully capture the slight difference in intention, but I'm open a better explanation.)</sub>